# getActivity() / context in a ViewHolder in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewholder, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm building a ViewHolder and Adapter for a Fragment and when I try to make an OnClick for the ViewHolder, none of the contexts I pass in work. There is no `activity` from `getActivity()` that I can use, and `p0!!.context` nor `itemView.context` work either. Where should I be getting my context from, and how do I reference it?

```
package com._________.criminalintent

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast

class CrimeListFragment: Fragment() {
    private var mCrimeRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var mAdapter: CrimeAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // fragment_crime_list.xml has a RecyclerView element = crime_recycler_view
    // inflate the fragment into the activity
        val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false)

        // grab the recyclerView and give it a required layoutManager
        mCrimeRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view)
        mCrimeRecyclerView!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        updateUI()
        return view
    }

    private fun updateUI() {
        val crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(activity)
        val crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes()
        mAdapter = CrimeAdapter(crimes)
        // Connect the adapter to the recyclerView
        mCrimeRecyclerView!!.adapter = mAdapter
    }

    /**
     * in Kotlin, we must give the view passed into the constructor directly
     * as a substitute for a super() call
     *
     * create a ViewHolder that holders the crime list item's view
     *
     * super(itemView) = super(inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false))
     * MUST give it the direct value in Kotlin
     */
    private class CrimeHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater?, parent: ViewGroup):
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false)),
        View.OnClickListener {

        private var mCrime: Crime? = null

        /**
         * When given a crime, this CrimeHolder will update the title and date for this Crime
         */
        fun bind(crime: Crime) {
           mCrime = crime
            val titleTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_title)
            val dateTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_date)
            titleTextView.text = mCrime!!.mTitle
            dateTextView.text = mCrime!!.mDate.toString()
        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

            Toast.makeText(WHAT_TO_PUT_HERE, "${mCrime!!.mTitle} clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT / 2)
                .show()
    }
}


    private class CrimeAdapter(private var mCrimes: MutableList<Crime>):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder>() {

        /**
         * - Calls our CrimeHolder to make our custom ViewHolders
         * - Called by RecyclerView when it needs a new view to display
         * - Gets the layoutInflater from the ViewGroup and returns a CrimeHolder of it
         */
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): CrimeHolder
        = CrimeHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context), parent)


        /**
         * Bind the crime (data) to the CrimeHolder
         */
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CrimeHolder?, position: Int) {
            holder!!.bind(mCrimes[position])
        }

        /**
         * Sees how many items are in the RecyclerView that need to be shown
         */
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = mCrimes.size
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is not a code review, but here's my 2 cents. By setting your views as `lateinit var` you don't need the `!!` everywhere.

Comment: Holy crap. How have I never known this... Thank you!

Comment: Talking about 2 cents, always use the closest context. You need context for a layout manager? Use `recyclerView.context`. /// `inflater` in `onCreateView` is never null. `container` may be null. /// Don't put context in `CrimeHolder`! View holders can access their `itemView` and therefore `itemView.context`.

Comment: In Kotlin, nested classes are static by default. If you need inner class, just write `inner class`. Be careful with memory leaks!

Comment: @EugenPechanec never knew that you could change the null safety on overrides. Thank you!

Comment: @Miha_x64, can you tell me where I might have memory leaks?

Comment: @user3338275, for example, if you are going to create an inner Loader, after Fragment recreation loader will leak the original Fragment.

Comment: @Miha_x64 Tbh I have no idea what you mean by loader, or pretty much anything you said.

Comment: @user3338275 consider googling what things are Loader in Android, inner class in Java/Kotlin, and memory leak in Java/Kotlin.

Comment: if i have an inner class in my adapter is it likely to leak. ive passed it the view created in onViewCreated and im using this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your implementation you can safely use `Context` from `View` provided to your `OnClickListener`

```
override fun onClick(p0: View) {
          Toast.makeText(p0.context, "${mCrime!!.mTitle} clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT / 2)
                .show()
    }
```

Just remember to set onclick:

```
fun bind(crime: Crime) {
           mCrime = crime
            val titleTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_title)
            val dateTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_date)
            titleTextView.text = mCrime!!.mTitle
            dateTextView.text = mCrime!!.mDate.toString()
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

Moreover all Kotlin classes are nested (`static`) by default. So your `private class CrimeHolder` is equivalent to `private static class CrimeHolder` in Java. That's why you don't have access to `getActivity()` from within `CrimeHolder`

Comment: The `setOnClickListener` worked! So regardless of having an onClick, I need to set the onClick for the view. Why is `this` being passed in? And I thought static is the Kotlin equivalent of companion object.

Comment: `val titleTextView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.crime_title)` and such should be defined directly on the view holder *not locally every time the view holder is bound*. That defeats the whole purpose of view holder - caching found views.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thank you, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itemView.context` property inside your holder.

Edit:
The reason why your `onClick` doesn't "work" (is not called) is because you haven't registered the `onClickListener`, for example:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

inside your holder `init` or `bind`.

Comment: @user3338275 see edited answer. You haven't set your OnClickListener anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
 itemView.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(itemView.context, "Item is clicked $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        }
```